Why is "going faster around a circle" not a homotopy from the identity map on $S^1$ to a constant map?
Let $S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be the unit circle, and consider the map $f : S^1 \times [0, 1] \to S^1$ defined for $\theta \in [0, 1)$ and $t \in [0, 1]$ as:
$$f(e^{2\pi i\theta}, t) = \cases{
e^{\frac{2\pi i\theta}{t}} & if $\theta < t$\\
1 & if $\theta \geq t$
}$$
Then $f(-, 0)$ is constant and $f(-, 1)$ is the identity map on $S^1$. Intuitively, for all $t > 0$, the map $f(-, t)$ goes around the circle once and then stays still for the rest of the time, and as $t$ approaches $0$ it goes around the circle faster and faster until at $t = 0$, it does so "instantaneously", or not at all.
But the identity map on $S^1$ is not homotopic to a constant map, so this cannot be a homotopy. What goes wrong here?

Although each slice of $f$ is continuous when either coordinate is fixed, on the whole, $f$ is not continuous. For instance, $\{-1\} \subseteq S^1$ is closed, but its preimage $\{(e^{2\pi i\theta}, t) \in S^1 \times [0, 1] : t = 2\theta > 0\}$ is not closed, as it does not contain the limit point $(1, 0)$ where $t = 2\theta = 0$.
